# netbeans design view error invalid byte

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having issue when I switch to design view on netbeans Do you have any idea what is going on ? How get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever been able to use design view before?

Comment: my design was working with same version of netbeans 7.4 i just switch to new pc and here netbeans 7.4 installed as well but having this problem